# How Do I Get Multiple Functions to Work onclick for a Button?

Tags: javascript, onclick, addeventlistener

I'm trying to create a button that does two things when clicked. The first, toggle between a hamburger menu icon and a times icon (X). The second action is to change a side navigation element's width from 0px to 250px and then back to 0px if clicked again (syncing up with the hamburger menu switching from and X and back to a hamburger). I've been able to get various parts of these actions to work, but haven't been able to bring them all together. Here are the functions I currently have:

```
<script>
        
     document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", myFunctionTwo);

    function myFunctionTwo() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    }    
        
    function myFunction(x) {
      x.classList.toggle("fa-times");       
      x.classList.toggle("fa-bars");     
    }
        
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<button id="test">
<i onclick="myFunction(this)" class="fa fa-bars"></i>    
</button>        
    
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">    
<a href="#">NFL</a>
<a href="#">NBA</a>
<a href="#">MLB</a>   
</div>
```

Something tells me that my onclick function for the i element should be combined with the event listener for my button but I cannot get it to work properly. I also need to add a way to hide the sidenav back to a 0px width if the button is clicked again.

What is the proper way to go about doing something like this?

Comment: To handle multiple functions, create a new function which executes the two functions in order. And bind the new function as a handler.

Comment: The advantage to `addEventListener` is you can call it more than once to add more than one event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try combining the two functions into one callback. This is just to get you started.

```js
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunctionTwo(open) {
    if(open){
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    }else{
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0px";
    }
}    

function myFunction(event) {//have myFunction queue the work for everything that needs to be done.
  if(! event.currentTarget.opened){
    event.currentTarget.opened = true;
    myFunctionTwo(true);
  }else{
    event.currentTarget.opened = false;
    myFunctionTwo(false);
  }

  var x = event.currentTarget.children[0];
  x.classList.toggle("fa-times");       
  x.classList.toggle("fa-bars");     
}
```

```css
#mySidenav{
  width:0px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:1px solid #333;
}
#test{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
}
```

```html
<button id="test">
<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>    
</button>        

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">    
<a href="#">NFL</a>
<a href="#">NBA</a>
<a href="#">MLB</a>   
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I'm a bit confused as to what you mean by combining the two functions.  When I implement your solution, it works almost perfectly.  The only hiccup is that if you click directly on the icon, the icon doesn't change.  But if you click on other areas of the button, it does.  I've tried adding the icon toggle into the myFunctionTwo, but I've broken the function...

Comment: By combining the two functions I meant that you just bind one event handler to the click event, and then have all logic flow from that one function. in this case I left the classList toggle in the handler directly, but you could imagine having a `function clickhandler(event)` that in turn called `myFunction()` and `myFunctionTwo()` instead. As for why the icon isn't changing when you click it directly...  I goofed and left the `<i onclick="myFunction(this)" `...  that should be removed. My bad. I'll edit the answer

Comment: to clarify, the problem with having that `onclick` in the snippet was causing the code to execute twice, once for the click handler on the icon, and then again when the event bubbled up to the button. If you aren't clear on how event bubbling works, it's a pretty useful (and important) concept in JS and you should read up on it. But basically an event traverses every parent "bubbling" up to the body. so that's how the code was executing twice, causing the icon to toggle twice (back to it's initial state)

Comment: thank you for responding!  i did just read up a bit on bubbling in JS because i wasn't in any way familiar with it.  it makes sense to me why the onclick snippet caused the code to execute twice instead of once.  but, even after removing the snippet from the icon element, i'm still only getting the icon to switch if i click outside of the icon, somewhere else on the button.  you've done more than enough so far, but if you can offer me any more advice, it'd be welcomed!  thanks so much!

Comment: i've done a bit of research.  when i click directly on the icon, i'm getting an error message that reads 'Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined at HTMLButtonElement.myFunction'

Comment: @mizDawg that's my bad again... I feel embarrassed... it should be `event.currentTarget`, not `event.target`. target will be the originator of the event (in that case the icon, which has no children) and currentTarget will be the evaluation context (what is currently bound in the bubbling). I'll correct my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try following

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("fa-times");
  x.classList.toggle("fa-bars");
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").classList.toggle("width_250px");
}
```

```css
.sidenav {
  width: 0px;
}

.width_250px {
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<i onclick="myFunction(this)" class="fa fa-bars">Toggle</i>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="#">NFL</a>
  <a href="#">NBA</a>
  <a href="#">MLB</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this and let CSS handle more for you.

```js
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", toggleNav);

function toggleNav()
{
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
  body.classList.toggle('nav-open');
}
```

```css
body div#mySidenav {
  display:none;
  width:150px;
  background:yellow;
}
body button#test .fa-times {
 display:none;
}
body.nav-open button#test .fa-times {
 display:inline;
}
body.nav-open button#test .fa-bars {
 display:none;
}
body.nav-open div#mySidenav {
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<button id="test">
<i class="fa fa-bars">-</i> 
<i class="fa fa-times">x</i>
</button>        

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">    
<a href="#">NFL</a>
<a href="#">NBA</a>
<a href="#">MLB</a>   
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<body>

<button id="test">
<i class="fa fa-bars"></i> 
<i class="fa fa-times"></i>
</button>        

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">    
<a href="#">NFL</a>
<a href="#">NBA</a>
<a href="#">MLB</a>   
</div>

</body>
```